# How to implement dependency injection of db context

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to adapt this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8) on how to make a shopping cart in asp.net core mvc but I'm having trouble with the db context. I get the following error:

**Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'StoreContext.StoreContext(DbContextOptions)'**

I've already looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384313/there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal-parameter-op) and implemented the solution but it still hasn't fixed my problem.

Here is my code:

```
    public class ShoppingCart
    {
        private readonly StoreContext db;

        public ShoppingCart(StoreContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }

        public const string CartessionKey = "CartId";

        public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContext context)
        {
            var cart = new ShoppingCart();
            cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
            return cart;
        }
}
```

If I change the code, as suggested, to the following:

```
    public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContext context)
    {
        **var cart = new ShoppingCart(db);**
        cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
        return cart;
    }
```

Then I get a new error:

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

So, despite the corrections, it seems that it's still not injecting the db properly. Any guidance?

And here for the storecontext:

```
    public StoreContext(DbContextOptions<StoreContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Here's is the connection string in my startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StoreContext")));
    }
```

Comment: No, I already looked at that question. I'm using constructor injection to pass the db context but then when I go to create an instance of the shopping cart, I get an error. "Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ShoppingCart.db'"

Comment: Your comment refers to a new error but you don't show the new code.

Comment: Updated with the new code and error message

Comment: Right, well, that's just fundamental C#. You can't use a non-static field in a static method like that. Take static off the GetCart method.

Comment: You're right. I fixed that but now I'm getting NullReferenceException because nothing is getting passed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you show us your startup.cs file? I think it has something to do with it

Okay I missed completely the problem, my bad apparently you are creating your shopping cart new class without passing the context that you are injecting on top,

try changing your line to

```
var cart = new ShoppingCart(db);
```

Comment: I added the code from my startup.cs file for configure services.

Comment: did this helped you?

Comment: I added that line but I'm still getting the error when I try this line:             var cart = new ShoppingCart();

Comment: check my new edit

Comment: Tried this. Now I'm getting a new error: Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ShoppingCart.db'