# Entity Framework 7 Scaffold-DbContext overrides OnConfiguring without checking if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)

Tags: entity-framework

I switched from EF6 to EF7 and, rebuilding my classes using the `Scaffold-DbContext` command, I noticed that the generated `DbContext` has a different implementation of the `OnConfiguring` method.

EF6:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("...");
        }
    }
```

EF7:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("...");
    }
```

My new package references are:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.1"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.1"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.1"

This missing check is really painful and I'd like to avoid to manually insert it again whenever I rebuild my classes.

To avoid the problem, I thought to use a class derived from the scaffolded DbContext, implementing the `OnConfiguring` method.

Although this works, it seems to me really weird, as I have to override an existing method with one that... does absolutely nothing!

Is there a better way of doing the job? Maybe, a way to tell `Scaffold-DbContext` not to scaffold the `OnConfiguring` method at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-NoOnConfiguring` option

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

Comment: This option removes the constructor wich leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384313/there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal-parameter-op